# Miele dishwasher wires burnt. No power anymore. Is it fixable and worth calling someone?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, dishwasher

I hope I can get more info about my dishwasher issue. It stop working two days ago and no power at all. I opened the control panel today and noticed burnt components/wires. Anyone could tell me if I can do anything? Easy fix or not? Is it worth calling someone ?

It’s a Miele dishwasher that I bought about 5 years ago. Model Futura classic plus 3D

[image]

Comment: Because it has smoke on it, I dont thnk its the plug.  If you want to be brave then you need to track where it actually came from.  And post a photo of the component or board

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How old is the dishwasher? You still may have warranty on it making it Mieles problem to fix.

Comment: No, nobody can tell you if _you_ can do anything - we have no idea about your skill level or ability/willingness to learn. If it's not something you know or are willing to learn about, then your options are "call someone" or "replace without looking", only _you_ can decide that.

Comment: How old is this dishwasher? This looks like it might be easily repaired. Surely it is worth it to fix a Miele appliance, a premium brand. Call Miele and get them to refer you to a Miele certified repair service. Where are you located?

Comment: I’m in Vancouver

Comment: Vancouver BC  Canada should have Miele certified repair services available. Even Vancouver WA USA should have them, but presumably you are in BC. Send them the pic and they can have the replacement part with them. Should save money.

Comment: Awesome, I’m doing it right now. I know what the parts are called now. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], @AudreyDion! You'll want to take the [tour] to learn your way around here. Note that an up arrow click is the way to say thanks, and clicking the check mark is the way to tell others that this was the most useful answer. It's often an indicator to others, too, not to bother wasting time answering (or even reading) a question. If you find that an answer doesn't provide you with the info you were looking for, don't click the check mark.

Comment: It does seem that your answer has come from the comments here, so ask someone (Jim) to write it up as an answer so you can vote for it and hit the check mark there. Also, if you [edit] the question to reword it to ask _how_ it can be fixed, rather than _can you_ or _is it worth it_, it'll get reopened so a new answer can be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your question "how/why did this happen"?

Those are called "stab in plugs".

The wires are just pushed in and held by a metal springs.

If not done correctly they will loose contact and start arching, and that is what you see.

If you are lucky it was just a bad plug so replacing it might work.

Comment: $20 worth of parts is certainly cheaper than replacing a whole dishwasher. OTOH, if it's $500, then it's probably not worth it. How do _you_ know which it is to categorically say "it's not worth it"?

Comment: If you don't have the skill (and information, which _we_ don't have) to identify, find, and install the parts, it's $20 plus an hour or three of labor, which is the higher cost.

Comment: Hi, sorry I’m new on the website. I’m pretty handy in general, willing to learn, but what I was looking for is any information about how this could happened, if it’s common and if there’s anything I can do to investigate any further and maybe save money. Otherwise, I’m happy to pay for repair but so many times we call someone and it’s something easy to do. I’m pretty handy and like to learn. I’m in Vancouver.